# Django filter queryst after retrieving

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I'm making a django website and due to the load on the database I'd like to filter the queryset after retrieving it.

```py
files = Files.objects.get(folder_id=folder_id)

first_file = files.objects.filter(sequence = 0)
```

This example throws me error, same if I tried for loop. So is it possible to filter the retrieved queryset without interacting with database ?

Comment: Please show the full traceback for the error and surrounding code.  As an initial guess, you probably shouldn't use the ".objects" piece in the second call.

Comment: In case of showed example its "Manager isn't accessible via Files instances" and in case of for loop " 'Files' object is not iterable" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run `get` that executes the query, returns a single `Files` object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get

you would want to change the *first line* to `filter` (which won't actually execute the query yet)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter

and the *second line* to `get`.

```py
files = Files.objects.filter(folder_id=folder_id)

first_file = files.objects.get(sequence = 0)
```